# SQLite syntax ERROR

Tags: android, sqlite

Constantly getting this error E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "stationId": syntax error

```
  String createReviewTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + STATION_ID + " VARCHAR," +
            "" + STATION_NAME + " VARCHAR," + STATION_LOCATION + " VARCHAR," +
            "" + STATION_TYPE + " VARCHAR," + STATION_COUNTY + " VARCHAR," +
            "" + WIFI_REVIEW + " VARCHAR," +
            "" + TOILET_REVIEWS + " VARCHAR," + TROLLEY_REVIEW + " VARCHAR," +
            "" + LIFT_REVIEW + " VARCHAR," +
            "" + STEP_FREE_REVIEW + " VARCHAR," + TICKET_MACHINE_REVIEW + " VARCHAR" + ")";
    dbm.execSQL(createReviewTable );

    String createRatingsTable= "CREATE TABLE " + RATING_TABLE_NAME + "(" + REVIEW_ID + " " +
            "INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , " + STATION_ID + " VARCHAR," +
            "" + WIFI_RATING + " INTEGER, " + TOILET_RATING + " INTEGER," +
            "" + TROLLEY_RATING + " INTEGER, " + LIFT_RATING + " INTEGER, " +
            "" + STEP_FREE_RATING + " INTEGER," + TICKET_MACHINE_RATING + " INTEGER," +
            "" + "FOREIGN KEY " + STATION_ID + " REFERENCES review " + STATION_ID + ")";
    dbm.execSQL(createRatingsTable);
```

Comment: from which table ? first or second?

Comment: @Shvet These changes are **meaningless**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the **brackets** around the stationid field. For reference: http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Change this

```
"" + "FOREIGN KEY " + STATION_ID + " REFERENCES review " + STATION_ID + ")";
```

to this

```
"" + "FOREIGN KEY (" + STATION_ID + ") REFERENCES review (" + STATION_ID + "))";
```